# SQL SUM, COUNT for only unique id

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions, exists

I want to calculate sum and count for only unique ids.

```
SELECT COUNT(orders.id), SUM(orders.total), SUM(orders.shipping) FROM "orders"
INNER JOIN "designer_orders" ON "designer_orders"."order_id" = "orders"."id" 
WHERE (designer_orders.state = 'pending' OR
       designer_orders.state = 'dispatched' OR
       designer_orders.state = 'completed')
```

- Do this only for unique orders ids.
- Add orders.total only if orders.id is unique. Same goes for shipping.
- Avoid adding duplicates.

For example, `orders` table inner joined `designer_orders` table:

```
OrderId Total Some designer order column
 1       1000  2
 1       1000  3
 1       1000  5
 2       100   7
 3       133   8
 4       1000  10
 4       1000  20
```

In this case:

- count of orders should be 4.
- total of orders should be 2233.

Schema:

- One order has many designer orders.
- One designer order has only one order.

Comment: There is no way to answer your question with info you provided so far

Comment: @Alexander what more do need. please specify

Comment: `CREATE for your tables and sample `INSERT`s

Comment: This is still quite unclear, IMO. Can you create a SQLfiddle which demos your scenario?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer just check the update. if you still feel u need a fiddle then let me know

Comment: Maybe others can get it from this, but I think it'd be nice to see explicitly what your tables are and what data are in them. I just think I don't understand what exactly you're asking and without knowing what data you're starting with, it's hard to guess.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @peterm i have mentioned it in the question. I written a dummy table and down i have written what i want in that case

Comment: @ChrisFarmer http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4abe5/1 ... this was what i looking for..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
SELECT COUNT(o.id) no_of_orders, 
       SUM(o.total) total, 
       SUM(o.shipping) shipping 
  FROM orders o JOIN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT order_id
      FROM designer_orders
     WHERE state IN('pending', 'dispatched', 'completed')
) d 
    ON o.id = d.order_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/4abe5/1)** demo

Comment: one favor can you please explain how the join keyword works on the sub query

Comment: It works the same as with usual tables. From the derived table (that you called a subquery) we return `order_id`s of interest (with proper states) and then we JOIN it `orders` effectively filtering out all mismatches.

Comment: so does that work as where clause. say where order_ids = whatever the subquery returns

Comment: In `WHERE` clause you have to use either `IN` or `EXISTS` in order do the same. `JOIN`s usually optimized better.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only interested whether *any* row with qualifying `status` *exists* in the table `designer_orders`, the most obvious query style would be an [**`EXISTS`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join. Typically fastest with potentially many duplicate rows in n-table:

```
SELECT COUNT(o.id)     AS no_of_orders
      ,SUM(o.total)    AS total
      ,SUM(o.shipping) AS shipping
FROM   orders o
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   designer_orders d
   WHERE  d.state = ANY('{pending, dispatched, completed}')
   AND    d.order_id = o.id
   );
```

[-> SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ea6f8/1)

For fast `SELECT` queries with bigger tables (and at some cost for write performance), you would have a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) like:

```
CREATE INDEX designer_orders_order_id_idx ON designer_orders (order_id)
WHERE state = ANY('{pending, dispatched, completed}');
```

The index condition must match the `WHERE` condition of the query to talk the query planner into actually using the index.

A *partial* index is particularly attractive if there are many rows with a `status` that does *not* qualify. Else, an index without condition might be the better choice overall.